# Automatically Scrolling Grid Inside ScrollViewer Results in Flickering/Pulsing Effect

Tags: wpf, vb.net, grid, scrollviewer

I'm developing a constantly scrolling display of information related to parts coming off a paint line at a manufacturing facility.  The information gets regularly refreshed and is displayed to employees on a horizontally oriented 70" LCD monitor (I'm using a standard Vizio 70" 4K LCD TV for my testing).  Here is a quick screenshot for reference...

[image: Example of Display]

I'm using a WPF form inside VB.net and creating a series of grids with embedded text boxes to make up all various cells you see in the screenshot.  This is done at runtime since it needs to be dynamic.  In order to get the whole thing to "scroll" automatically the main grid is embedded in a `scrollviewer` control and I use a timer to increment the the VerticalOffset property of the `scrollviewer` every X number of milliseconds to scroll through all the information until it reaches the end.

I should mentioned that the entire grid is usually comprised of less than 100 total rows of information.

Everything works fine with this solution except that when the grid is autoscrolling through the rows I end up will this pulsing/flickering effect, it is especially prominent when running the program on the large display.  I've read about double buffering but this is already a WPF form so I'm not sure it applies here or if can even be applied to a `scrollviewer` or `grid` control.  Here is a short video that shows what I'm talking about (note: it pausing the scrolling after every couple of rows is intentional)...

[Youtube Video Example](https://youtu.be/j-qqlQBsHQg)

Any ideas on what I can do to minimize this effect when scrolling?

Right now I'm setting up a timer to run every 30 milliseconds...

```
Dim scrollTimer As DispatcherTimer = New DispatcherTimer()    
AddHandler scrollTimer.Tick, AddressOf scrollTimer_Tick    
scrollTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 30)     
scrollTimer.Start()
```

And then scrolling the vertical offset by 1...

```
scrlPaintLineStatus.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrlPaintLineStatus.VerticalOffset + 1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about scrolling less often by a larger amount, e.g. 3 units every 100ms?

Comment: or more often but less than 1 unit?
i m not sure but i would expect it to be a double value that will allow that

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have tried playing with the timespan on the timer and the verticaloffset increment.  Doesn't seem to have any effect on the "pulsing/flickering" effect unfortunately.  It does actually make the scrolling motion look a little jerkier so keeping it incrementing by 1 or less is preferred.